# Lua in Apache HTTPD - Some function are not defined

Tags: apache, lua, apache2.4

I am using Apache httpd 2.4 with Lua 5.1.4. I 'm trying to use the function that comes with `r` object of each request, as explained here:
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_lua.html#functions
Some function, like `r:write()` and `r:md5()` works well, but most of them doesn't work, this is a minimal list:
- `r:setcookie`
- `r:getcookie`
- `r:escape`

The error is:
`AH01471: Lua error: /path/to/lua/file: attempt to call method 'getcookie' (a nil value)`

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I see at least r:setcookie was added in the maintenance stream, 2.4.7, and had further refinements. You are likely on RedHat's distribution which is 2.4.6 + fixes, or something similar.  If updating doesn't work, I would find a different distribution or build httpd from source.  Or at least mod_lua!